# Active PFC design and simulation with reactive loads

Tags: inverter, generator, power-factor-correction

While designing the building blocks of a double conversion pure sine wave inverter designed for standby generators,
and specifically the AC to 400V DC conversion required to feed the pure sine wave inverter H-bridge done by an active PFC boost converter,
I decided to put the PFC based on LT8312 to the (simulated) test of a variable impedance load that would mimic a reactive load downstream.
Since plugging the pure sine wave simulated circuitry would lead to substantially longer simulation times, I gave the variable impedance test load a go.
The idea is to use a behavioral voltage source to model the load impedance using the following function:

$$
R_{dc} = R_{load}/(abs(sin(2*pi*t*f_{ac}) + \varphi ) +\varepsilon )
$$

\$ R_{load} \$
being the effective load resistance seen by the downstream inverter

\$ f_{ac} \$ being the inverter AC line frequency

\$ \varphi \$ being the phase angle used to test for reactive conditions downstream

\$ \varepsilon \$ being a small value to avoid \$ R_{dc} \$ from reaching infinity.
This minimum \$ R_{dc} \$ condition is reached when the downstream inverter voltage crosses zero)

The goal as you have seen is to model the current seen at the DC link stage if the inverter was connected and connected to an arbitrary load impedance.

The idea is then to step \$ \varphi \$ and analyze the AC input current waveform to the active PFC to see how well the PFC does his job.
It is difficult to give a definite answer using LTspice charts since the current is not sinusoidal in nature, but at least periodic, and calculating the power factor in these conditions
require summing using Fourier series.

Using a purely visual interpretation, I just checked the \$ I_{max} \$ point at the input current waveform and checked the corresponding angle to the Vmax point on the AC input voltage.
**From what I see, there is more or less always a 45° degrees leading current at the ac input when looking at I_max, but the second capture with an inductive load show a more spread out current, which I believe is closer to a unity PF**

**Results with 45° degrees leading reactive load:**

- I(R7) is the current on the AC input of the PFC converter
- I(R2) is the current on the DC link
- V(line)-V(neutral) is the voltage on the AC input
- V(out_pfc) is the PFC output voltage
- V(pf_load2) should be interpreted ad R2 resistance
  [image: Results with 45° degrees leading reactive load:]
  **Results with 45° degrees lagging reactive load:**
  [image: Results with 45° degrees lagging reactive load:]
  **PFC circuit**
  [image: PFC_circuit]

So here are my questions:

Since I am using a large capacitor bank for the PFC output stages, it makes sense that the PFC would still be seen as a capacitive load at the AC input.

1. Should I conclude that standard, non interleaved PFC boost converters will always maintain a capacitive (leading) power factor at the input if the load is capacitive?
   And that this is mainly dependent on the PFC output capacitor bank total capacitance?
   As far as I know, leading power factor are not so much of a concern on the utility grid where lagging power factor dominates, but it seems that it is bad news for a small standby generator (resulting in unstable voltage regulation, heating).
2. Should I be concerned and should I review my design? Lowering output capacitance is not really an option because I need quite long hold times in my design and also because it makes the feedback compensation network design trickier (now it is sluggish, overcompensated but stable).

Comment: Your output voltage should be DC and hence a reactive load makes no sense.

Comment: The current should have been sinusoidal (try filtering it) but, if it isn't, then something in your design is off, somewhere. Also, you can model the load with two current sources as `sin 0 4 50 0 0 [-45,135] load` in parallel; more efficient.

Comment: Andy, assuming a passive linear load : yes. The load in this case is a pure sine wave inverter and there could well be an inductive load like a motor downstream, hence the current does not stay constant in that case at the DC level. Even if the inverter load is purely resistive, if the inverter phase is not locked to the input AC, input current will not be in phase with the input AC voltage.

Comment: Bigger DC link capacitance and that problem goes away.

Comment: winny, It seems indeed that the LT8312 macromodel test fixture has no issue. my design is simply a scaled-up version up to 1600W, with some modifications coming from the datasheet typical applications. Will revert some changes / go for a lighter load and test again.

Comment: Problem solved. I did not scale the current sense resistor (sense pin) properly. Using a 7 milliohm resistor ensures a unity PF at full load. I assume that using a differential setup op-amp would be even better, allowing lower values of the shunt resistor and would allow max peak current tuning.